# Chaining jQuery selectors :lt and :gt

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, chaining

I have a table with more than 9 rows.

If I do this : `$('table tr:gt(3):lt(6)')`, shall I receive 3 or 6 elements at the end, and why? Are all selectors applied to the same primary selection, or are they successively applied on different selections?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They're applied sequentially, so first you will filter away the first four elements (`:gt(3)`), then you will filter away all elements after the sixth (`:lt(6)`) element of the already filtered set.

Imagine this HTML:

```
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
```

Then do the following jQuery:

```
$('br:gt(3):lt(6)').addClass('sel');
```

You will now have:

```
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<br class="sel"/><br class="sel"/>
<br class="sel"/><br class="sel"/>
<br class="sel"/><br class="sel"/>
<br/><br/>
```

Comment: Note that the `:lt(n)` and `:lt(n)` selectors are 0-indexed and non-inclusive.

Answer (score 28):

I suggest you use the slice() method instead.

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice#startend

```
$('table tr').slice(2, 5).addClass("something");
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but is a clearer way of doing the selection.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you'd chain lt and gt in this way, so perhaps subtenante will find this useful.

Comment: Yep, that's actually useful, although it does only partially answer the question. +1 though :)

Comment: Why is this better?  If there are 1000 table rows, this causes 1000 elements to be selected, only to slice out the four of interest.  At least in the OP's version, jQuery has the chance to filter during selection (which I hope it does).

Comment: @harpo http://jsperf.com/lt-vs-slice I ran this in Chrome and IE10, both times slice was quicker.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite what you might think-

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/izica)**

Basically, the second filter is applied sequentially, to the matched set of the first filter.

For example, on a table with 10 rows, `:gt(3)` will filter to elements 5 - 10, then `:lt(6)` will be applied to the 6 elements, not filtering any.

if you add **/edit** to the demo URL, you can play with the selector and see for yourself. If you change the second filter to `:lt(2)`, you get rows 5 and 6 highlighted in red

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `:lt(6)` will be ignored in that selection, so it will return everything greater than 3 in this intsance.

However, if you switch it over, it will work as expected

```
$('table tr:lt(6):gt(3)')
```

will return 2 rows (only row 4 and 5 is between 6 and 3).

**edit:**using v.1.3.2

And also, `lt(6)` isn't ignored, not just working as I expected it to. So `:gt(3):lt(6)` will in fact return 6 elements (if you have enough rows, that is)

Comment: Didn't work that way on the sample that I tried.  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Not true, `:lt(6)` will be applied, you just didn't see it because `:gt(3)` returned more than 6 elements. However, it will work like you said if you switch them around.

Comment: aha! so it filters everything greater than 3, then does a new filter on what ever is recieved from that...nice.