# JQuery Multiples?

Tags: jquery

Does anybody now how I would be able to select the multiples of html elements. For this example I am interested in selecting every 4th element through the 7th element, the 8th element through the 11th element, and so on.

Comment: Take a look at combining the `:lt` and `:gt` selectors to select a range. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137182/chaining-jquery-selectors-lt-and-gt

Answer (score 2):

You can try combining `nth-child` and `not` as follows:

```
:nth-child(-n+7):not(:nth-child(-n+3))
```

It might seem weird, but the first `nth-child` select elements 1 through 7, and the second one removes elements 1 through 3, leaving the 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

the jquery selectors return an array, so you can actaully go

```
 var four_to_seven = [] 

 var $results = $('.myselector');

 for(var i in $results){
     if(i>=3 && i<=6){
          four_to_seven.push($results[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: `4to7` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: yeah I should have been paying more attention

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to select a "range" of elements. The term "multiples" threw me off. It isn't clean, but you could use nth-child like this:

```
$(":nth-child(4), :nth-child(5), :nth-child(6),:nth-child(7)")
```

API doc:
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery object holds a list of all the element it finds through a selector. You can use the an index from this list to get an item.

For example:

```
$("div")[1] <- second div in the document
$("div")[3] <- fourth div in the document.
```

You can use javascript to loop through them.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off, you could use the `:gt` and `:lt` selectors in tandem, e.g.:

```
var divs = $("div:gt(2):lt(4)"); // Fourth through seventh inclusive
```

If you want to loop through them in groups, the first number (the `:gt(x)`) changes, the second does not (as it applies to the result of the former): [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ileqeq) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ileqeq/edit)

Although I think if I were looping, I'd grab them all and then use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/). Your starting point (the fourth) is a bit odd because "fourth to seventh" and "eighth to eleventh" are both groups of four, but "first to third" is a group of three.

Using `slice` by groups of three:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var divs = $("div");
  var index;
  var group;

  // By threes rather than fours
  group = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < divs.length; index += 3) {
    ++group;
    divs.slice(index, index + 3).append(
      "<span>Group " + group + "</span>"
    );
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ovabuv) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ovabuv/edit)