# jQuery .on() event not working with :lt() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate click event on every table data `<TD>` except the last one `<td>` but It's just working with the First row not the rest.

HTML:

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS code:

```
$('.table tbody').on('click', 'tr td:lt(3)', function(){
    // Trying to check the click event
    console.log('working');
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/9Hphd/)

If i remove the `:lt(3)` selector then its working fine but i don't know why it's not working with **less then selector**?

Comment: @kayen no its not working, try to click on second or third row.

Comment: This is an interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137182/chaining-jquery-selectors-lt-and-gt

Comment: IMHO, you would be better off adding a specific `class` to the `td`s you want to identify - e.g.  `<td class"disabledTd">`. Your javascript code will depend less on how your html is setup, and allow you for smoother changes (suppose you have to add a columns ? or change their order ?)

Comment: @LeGEC thanks for information but according to my scenario the accepted answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is how the [**:lt() selector**](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) works:

> The index-related selectors (including this "less than" selector)
>   filter the set of elements that have matched the expressions that
>   precede them. They narrow the set down based on the order of the
>   elements within this matched set. For example, if elements are first
>   selected with a class selector (.myclass) and four elements are
>   returned, these elements are given indices 0 through 3 for the
>   purposes of these selectors.

In your case, `tr td` is matched first which matches 16 cells, then the first 3 elements from the resulting set are filtered. You could revise the code like this:

```
// trap clicks on .table tbody and filter all td elements
$('.table tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    if ($(this).index() < 3) {
        console.log('working');
    }
});
```

Or better, use the [**CSS3 :nth-child()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) selector which is [also available in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
// trap clicks on .table tbody and filter all td elements
// that are "-n+3"th child of their parent
$('.table tbody').on('click', 'td:nth-child(-n+3)', function () {
    console.log('working');
});
```

The nth-child selector is [explained here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
$('.table tbody tr').on('click', 'td:lt(3)', function(){
    console.log('working');
});
```

If you don't, it will take the first 3 td, of all tbody, not the one of each row (you can try your code with 5 instead of 3, and see what's happening : it will be applied on tr 1 : td 1, td 2, td 3, td 4 and tr2 : td 1 ( the first 5 td of tbody)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Hphd/2/)